# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: react-redux, ethereum, solidity, truffle, drizzle

I have a simple smart contract deployed on the local truffle env using migrate. I am using react-components package to work with the smart contract.

So my issue is that simple getters and setters are working, but when I try to run a method with 2-3 arguments I am getting this exception.

My truffleconfig is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "app/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    develop: { // default with truffle unbox is 7545, but we can use develop to test changes, ex. truffle migrate --network develop
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 6921975,
      gasPrice: 25000000000
    }
  },
  solc: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200
        }
    }
};
```

And in my react component I am calling like this:

```
  <div className="section">
    <h2>Testing Poni</h2>
    <p>
      This is a initial test to create Poni
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Stored Value: </strong>
      <ContractData
        drizzle={drizzle}
        drizzleState={drizzleState}
        contract="PoniOwnership"
        method="getMyPonies"
      />
    </p>
    <ContractForm drizzle={drizzle} contract="PoniOwnership" method="createPoni" />
  </div>
```

My solidity functions are like this:

```
function createPoni(string memory _code, string memory _imgLink) public onlyOwner poniIsUnique(_code){

    uint randDna = _generateRandomDna(_code);

    //!!pass imgHash here also later
    _createPoni(_code, _imgLink, randDna);
  }

function _createPoni(string memory _code, string memory _imgLink, uint _dna) private {

    uint id = ponies.push(Poni(msg.sender, _code, _imgLink, _dna, 0, true)) - 1;

    poniToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
    codeToId[_code] = id;
    ownerPoniCount[msg.sender] = ownerPoniCount[msg.sender].add(1);

    emit NewPoni(id, _code, _imgLink, _dna);
  }

struct Poni {
    address owner;
    string code;
    string imgLink;
    uint dna;
  }
```

I have tried to additionally send gas from the drizzle react-component as options are given here: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/drizzle/react/react-components, but it throws errors saying function is not payable. I am not able to figure out how to deal with this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set a higher gas for the transaction

You want to tweak the sendArgs({gas:}) on the ContractForm component.

https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/drizzle/react/react-components#contractform